# Reduction from $VC$ to $CD$

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, np, vertex-cover

We define the [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Computational_problem) as the problem of finding for a graph $G$, a cover of size $k$. A cover is a set of vertices such that every vertex has an edge to this set. We define CD (cycles destructor), as the set of vertices with the size $k$, whose removal will lead to a cycle-free graph. Show a reduction from VC to CD. In other words, prove that CD is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

Comment: I think by CD you mean FVS (feedback vertex set). There is already an answer to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709995/feedback-vertex-set-np-complete-proof

Answer (score 0):

The identity reduction:
for any graph G, if there is a VC V,
then for any cycle a $\exists .v \in V$. therefore, for any cycle, removal of one vertex will break the cycle.
Now you look for a set of size k that will fit to this definition.
Therefore V is a cycle destructor.
Side note, there can be a subset of V which will be also a vertex destructor, or even a set that has a vertex that it is not in any vertex cover.

Comment: You have just shown that if there is vertex cover of size $k$ then there is a CD of size $k$. However, to prove NP-hardness, you must also show that if there is a CD of size $k$ then there is vertex cover of size $k$ in $G$. And, your reduction is not sufficient to prove this.